# Как удалить лишние символы и оставить одни буквы и пробел

Tags: java

Вот такой вариант работает

```
private static void replace() {
    String t = "Мне очень нравится Тайланд*-+"; 
    System.out.println(t.replaceAll("[^а-яА-Я\\s]", ""));
}
```

Но надо принять множество и обработать, и уже такой вариант не работает

```
private static SortedSet<String> clearSet(SortedSet<String> set) {

    for (String string : set) {
        string.replaceAll("[^а-яА-Я\\s]", "");
        set2.add(string);
    }       
    return set2;        
}
```

Вопрос. Как написать логику, оставляя только буквы

Comment: Я думаю дело в том, что надо `set2.add(string.replaceAll("[^а-яА-Я\\s]", ""))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` — [неизменяемый](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82) класс. Метод [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) не изменяет саму строку, а возвращает новую, измененную строку.

Рассмотрим на примере:

```
String input = "ab";
String result = input.replaceAll("a", "");
System.out.println(input);  //выводится "ab", строка не изменилась
System.out.println(result); //выводится "b"
```

Соответственно, для исправления нужно обрабатывать возвращаемое из `replaceAll` значение.

Для этого можно объявить переменную:

```
for (String string : set) {
    String clearString = string.replaceAll("[^а-яА-Я\\s]", "");
    set2.add(clearString);
}
```

Или просто передать в `set2` результат:

```
for (String string : set) {
    set2.add(string.replaceAll("[^а-яА-Я\\s]", ""));
}
```

Comment: точно)), спасибо...про String знал, но.....Кстати как кинуть + в карму?

Comment: @maxaspire спасибо что приняли ответ, этого достаточно. По идее `replaceAll` уже принимает регулярку.

Comment: ясно...новая тема для меня